# cucumber defaults publishing to some URL?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to generate a report using Cucumber-jvm 6.11.0, and it works fine on my machine, when I put these properties in `junit-platform.properties` :

```
cucumber.publish.enabled=true
cucumber.plugin=pretty, json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json
cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
```

However, when I run it on Jenkins, I get an ConnectException during the publication :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.MessageFormatter.writeMessage(MessageFormatter.java:36)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SynchronizedEventBus.send(SynchronizedEventBus.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.emitTestRunFinished(CucumberExecutionContext.java:102)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:74)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:98)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineDescriptor.after(CucumberEngineDescriptor.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineDescriptor.after(CucumberEngineDescriptor.java:10)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1963)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1958)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1957)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1525)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:329)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.UrlOutputStream.getResponseBody(UrlOutputStream.java:111)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.UrlOutputStream.sendRequest(UrlOutputStream.java:83)
```

I tried with different combination of properties, and I see it starts happening the moment I enable the publishing, with only :

```
cucumber.publish.enabled=true
```

I am not finding the default behavior in the [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options), once we enable the publishing : where does it get published by default ? does it really try to upload  it through http ? (I guess the proxy is not configured when running on Jenkins, while it is found when running on my machine, hence the different behavior)

How come I still get this error when I simply try to write the html or json report on disk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable report publishing, it uploads test result to Cucumber cloud service and you get the unique URL that you (or anyone you share that link with) can use to access your report.

The report is self-destructive in 24 hours. You can find more details in official [Cucumber blog](https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/cucumber-reports/).

Comment: thanks. I thought the "publishing" and the "local report generation" were tied together, that's why I had enabled the publishing. But it's actually something totally different, so I can have cucumber.publish.enabled=false and still define cucumber.plugin for local report generation

Comment: Exactly. You can also set up `cucumber.publish.quiet=true` so that their banner won't annoy you.